# How to find the minimum and maximum value from an numpy array image in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, min

I do have some numpy array images and I want to find the minimum and maximum value of the element from a certain portion of the image by row and column of the array. Suppose, I do have a grayscale numpy image of (512,512), from that I want to find the minimum and the maximum data value between the last 20 columns.

I have made a red bounded box and I want to find the values from that box. I don't want to set the indexes of the row and column manually not all the images are equal in shape.

[image: The picture]

I have tried the following so far and got stuck here:

```
(r, c) = img.shape #returns the row and the column of the image

for x in range(r): #considering all the rows as shown in the image
   for y in range(c)[-20:]: #trying to consider only last 20 columns (incorrect maybe)
      a = np.min(img[i,j])
      b = np.max(img[i,j])
```

Comment: `a = np.min(img[i,j])` finds the minimum value of...a single pixel. Try passing a range instead.

Answer (score 0):

just use the two methods:
`np.max(img)`
`np.min(img)`

np.max --> return the maximum value of your image (in all rows)
np.min --> return the minimum value in all rows

Answer (score 0):

for maximum value :- `np.max(img[:,-20:])`

for minimum value :- `np.min(img[:,-20:])`

This will only take last 20 columns of the image

Comment: This works! Thanks. Do you also know how to take multiple rows/coloums for suppose I want to take 20-40 rows and only last 20 columns?

Comment: `img[r1:r2, c1:c2]` r1 is the start of index row 1, r2 is the end index of row. Similarly c1 and c2 are for columns.